# Suffisso diminutivo "-occhio" nelle parole come "pinocchio", "ranocchio/a", ecc. in italiano moderno

Tags: etymology, suffix

Recentemente mi sono interessato all'etimologia delle parole che finiscono con **-occhio**, come **pinocchio** e **ranocchio/a**. Prendiamo **ranocchio/a**, per esempio.  Nel vocabolario Treccani è scrito:

> **ranòcchia** s. f. [lat. *ranŭcŭla, dim. di rana «rana»]. – Lo stesso che ranocchio.

Poi, nella spiegazione di **ranocchio** si può leggere:

> **ranòcchio** s. m. [variante di ranocchia]. – 1. Nome pop. (insieme con la forma femm. ranocchia) della rana comune [...] Dim. ranocchiétto, ranocchino; accr., raro, ranocchióne; pegg. ranocchiàccio.

Secondo me, ne segue che questa parola non ha più una sfumatura diminutiva in italiano moderno (per lo meno, varie forme diminutive di **ranocchio** sono 
 elencate, e sovrapporre due diminutivi mi pare un po' eccessivo). Ciononostante, ho trovato questa informazione nel *La formazione delle parole in italiano* a cura di Maria Grossmann e Franz Rainer:

> Il suffisso  **occhio**, poco produttivo, aveva un valore diminutivo in latino, ma ora presenta la stessa ambiguità di  otto, con esiti ora diminutivi, come in **pinocchio**, **ranocchio**, pisocchio “pisolino”... 
>   (https://books.google.ru/books?id=ITchAAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=ranocchio&f=false)

Vorrei sapere se in italiano moderno parole di questo tipo si intendono e si percepiscono come diminutive (**pinocchio** - "a small pine", **ranocchio/a** - "a small frog, froggy", ecc.).

Comment: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/occhio_res-c6215ab4-0028-11de-9d89-0016357eee51

Comment: Grazie! Proprio non so come mai non m'è venuta in mente l'idea di cercare lo stesso suffisso "-occhio" nel Treccani. Mi scusi per i miei errori in italiano!

Comment: Che problema c'è? Siamo tutti qui per imparare. Confermo che anche secondo me il suffisso “-occhio” non è percepito come diminutivo o, seppure, molto blandamente (forse una ranocchia dà l'idea di essere più piccola di una rana).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dall'eccellente Rohlfs, *Grammatica storica dell'italiano e dei suoi dialetti*, paragrafo 1046

> -occhio. Deriva da *-ŭculus*, che in latino aveva un valore diminuitivo (*genuculum*, *verruculus*, *ranucula*). In italiano oramai questo significato generalmente è andato perduto: *ginocchio*, *ranocchio* (in Toscana è subentrato a *rana*), *finocchio*, *pinocchio* 'seme del pino', *pidocchio*, *pannocchia* 'spiga del granturco', *conocchia*, *santocchio* 'uomo bigotto', *batacchio* 'battaglio della campana', *capocchia* 'testa di spillo'.

A questo segue una lunga lista di voci regionali e toponimi che ho omesso per brevità.

Concordo con Rohlfs e con DaG nei commenti che il senso diminutivo di *-occhio* è andato quasi completamente perduto.

Comment: Altro caso, diminutivo: marmocchio.

Comment: @Ilmionome70: La Treccani la pensa diversamente: “[forse adattam. del fr. _marmot_, dalla radice _marm-_ (v. marmaglia)]” (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/marmocchio).

Answer (score 0):

Come già scritto da Denis Nardin, in latino: -ulus o -culus come suffisso a un  nome ne forma il diminutivo:

[image: Vocabolario Etimologico della Lingua Italiana]

Con probabilità anche in marmocchio, etimologia però non condivisa ma che se corretta conserverebbe la sfumatura diminutiva.

Comment: Qual è la fonte? Il sito etimo.it e quindi il vecchio dizionario etimologico del Pianigiani? Ti prego di ricordare che [non è considerato molto affidabile](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122/what-good-reference-works-on-italian-are-available-online/1202#1202).